# How to duplicate and clear a form element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

If I have the following html within a form:

```
<div class='example'>
   <div class='row'>
       <input name='first_field' type='text' value='Hello' />
       <input name='second_field' type='text' value='World!' />
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I go about creating a copy of this (first) 'row', with the value stripped out, so as to append thereafter as desired, for multiple user entries. The reason why a value may exist already (as in this example) is for cases where data is being edited. I would like to obtain:

```
   <div class='row'>
       <input name='first_field' type='text' value='' />
       <input name='second_field' type='text' value='' />
   </div>
```

I have thought along the lines of:

```
var row = $('.example').find('.row:first-child').clone(); 
row.find('[name]').each(function() {
  $(this).val('');
});
```

but this does not work in that it does not seem to remove the values, nor does it capture the outer html (the  wrapper).

Can anyone advise?

Thank you.

Comment: are you missing a ' after ".row:first-child"?

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your js.  `.find('.row:first-child)` should be `.find('.row:first-child')`, but as for cloning, <strike>the default behavior is to strip out the values.</strike> scratch that... that's only for cloning the actual input elements apparently.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yb2Ym/

```
var row = $('.example').find('.row:first-child').clone();  
row.find('[name]').each(function() {
  $(this).val('');
});
$(".row:last").after(row)
```